# Getting specific stats by page URL

Tags: google-analytics, visitors

I am sort of new to Google Analytics.

I would like to get stats on how many people visit certain state listings for example my URLs are:

`http://example.com/listing/NY`

`http://example.com/listing/FL`

`http://example.com/listing/TX`

and so on...

How can I get how many hits per state based on each URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple, find this at Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages

This gives the full overview for:

- pageviews
- unique pageviews
- time on page
- entrances
- bounce rate
- Exit %
- Page Value (when used with Goal)

To get these exact pages, you will need to perform an **advanced** filter with this filter:
`Include` `Page` `Begins With` `/listing/`

This is one of my favourite pages because it works so well with **Segments** and analysing user behaviour i.e. Australian users read blog posts longer than non-English users.

My favourite 'Segment' recipe in getting quick insights on user behaviour on website pages is Segmenting users by a content type or url pattern.

For example, for pages that `starts with` `example.com/listing/`, you can see the behaviour patterns of users who have visited these listing and how  they use your website versus other users.